# Regex parsing directory to find a pattern of folder

Tags: regex

Here is a typical directory name I have: `someFolder/S01/E01/0`. I want to use regex to parse it and determine whether it has a pattern like `<some folder>/S[0-9][0-9]/E[0-9][0-9]/0`. `E[0-9][0-9]` must be after `S[0-9][0-9]` and the directory name must end with `/0`

Here is what I tried which does not work:
`re.match('^(.*/)(\/E[0-9][0-9]\/0\/)$', '/ll/example/series/Seinfeld.1989/S01/E01/0')`

Comment: How about: `^(.*)(\/S[0-9][0-9]\/E[0-9][0-9]\/0)$`? [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pAxvIW/1/)

Comment: Or [`^[^/]+/S[0-9]+/E[0-9]+/0$`](https://regex101.com/r/xVsUEA/1). You should not say "does not work". Explain what it does and what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^.*\/S([0-9][0-9])\/E([0-9][0-9])\/0$
```

- `^` and `$` as starting and ending anchors
- `.*` matches any characters
- `\/S([0-9][0-9])` matches a slash `\` followed by literal `S` and then two digits to represents the season number
- `\/E([0-9][0-9])` matches a slash `\` followed by literal `E` and then two digits to represents the episode number
- `\/0` matches a slash `\` followed by a `0`

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pAxvIW/4/)

*As an added bonus, it'll get season number and episode number in capturing groups 1 and 2 respectively :)*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
re.match(r'.+/S\d\d/E\d\d/0$', '/ll/example/series/Seinfeld.1989/S01/E01/0')
```

This will match any folder that ends in `/S[0-9][0-9]/E[0-9][0-9]/0`, but the beginning is purely arbitrary. You can make it match only single level folders by: `^[^/]+/S\d\d/E\d\d/0$`. You can also group individual patterns if you need to extract their matches.

Answer (score 0):

`(.*)` Is greedy so it matches the full string including the slashes. Try `(.*?)` To make it ungreedy, then it will match until the next group.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this: `([^/]*)/(S[0-9][0-9])/(E[0-9][0-9])/0$`

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/NuqXdh/1)